# Converting a byte[] to short[] in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [byte array to short array and back again in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625573/byte-array-to-short-array-and-back-again-in-java)

the `encodeAudio()` method in Xuggler has the following parameters:

int streamIndes

short[] samples

long timeStamp

TimeUnit unit

Using `TargetDataLine` from `javax.sound.sampled` I can read the data into a `byte[]` array

```
byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[10000];
fromMic.read(tempBuffer,0,tempBuffer.length);
```

But the problem is that the `samples` argument needs `short[]`

Comment: [byte-array-to-short-array-and-back-again-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625573/byte-array-to-short-array-and-back-again-in-java)

Comment: I am not using BigEndian encoding.

Comment: It's not nearly as simple as that. You have a byte array with data in a specific format, and you need to do some conversion. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xuggler-users/cKLS5KmbEIM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are lucky enough that `byte` is "fully castable" to `short`, so:

```
// Grab size of the byte array, create an array of shorts of the same size
int size = byteArray.length;
short[] shortArray = new short[size];

for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    shortArray[index] = (short) byteArray[index];
```

And then use `shortArray`.

Note: as far as primitive type goes, Java always treats them in big endian order, so converting, say, byte `ff` will yield short `00ff`.

Comment: my `AudioFormat` object has set BigEndian to false. whill this be a problem?

Comment: Ouch... Yes that is, in which case the first comment is the solution for you.

Comment: and will it cause an issue if I set BigEndian to `true` because I do not know what that does. I am merely  setting it to true or false arbitrarily. :)

Comment: Typo... the i++ should be index++.

Comment: OK, let's take number 255: as a `byte`, this is `ff`. If you were to represent it on two bytes instead of one, on a little endian setup this would be `ff 00`, whereas on a big endian setup this would be `00 ff`. Note that network order is big endian, and that as I mentioned, Java's primitive types are all treated as big endian, even if the underlying CPU architectyre does not think that way (famous example: all x86/x86-64 archs). I suggest you treat everything as big endian, the code above will probably work. Note that `ByteBuffer` and friends also use big endian by default.

Comment: @phatfingers: your name tells it all, doesn't it ;) Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @fge I am stuck and I need help. Would you like me to include the code in the question??

Comment: @LittleChild certainly so, since all of StackOverflow can find what is wrong with it, if anything.

Comment: @fge sorry, but I am dumb