# Saving large short array android

Tags: java, android, serialization, io

I'm basically looking for a way to save and reload a few large arrays (about 5 million `short`) in a fastish way on Android. My app needs to save them in a way where I could get back to them much later, so I can't just hold them in memory...

So far, I've tried converting them to a `byte[]` array and they seem to save successfully, but I can't get the data back, this is how my saving code works (it's actually to separate functions, simplified here):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOuputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(data);
oos.close();
baos.close();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename); // valid absolute path
fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
fos.close();
```

And the loading part is where I get stuck, how do I get a `short[]` from a `byte[]`?
I also read that a database might work too, but is it quick enough?

I've looked all around Stackoverflow and Google and can't seem to find somebody with a similar problem, or at least a solution to it, but as a beginner I might have missed something obvious...

Answer (score 6):

If `data` is a `short[]` and you want to write the whole thing into a file, don't use a buffer in memory, write it directly.

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
try {
    oos.writeObject(data);
} finally {
    oos.close();
}
```

If you write it via `ObjectOutputStream`, you will have to read it via `ObjectInputStream` since it's not just writing the pure data but also some type information. If you put a `short[]` in, you get a `short[]` back (you could try to skip those bytes but you would have to analyze what the stream is actually writing). This also applies if your `ObjectOutputStream` writes into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

If you don't want to handle that mess, do what `ObjectOutputStream` basically does:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dos.writeShort(data[i]);
    }
} finally {
    dos.close();
}
```

`DataOutputStream` writes plain data so you can simply read the data directly as a `byte[]` if you want. If byte order matters: it's using Big-Endian.

---

Since this approach writes single bytes instead of chucks of `byte[]` it benefits from using a `BufferedOutputStream` in between. The default uses an 8kB buffer, but it can increased which could give even better results. Writing the data will now convert `short` into `byte`s in memory and once enough data is available the whole chunk will get pushed to low level OS functions to write it.

```
int bufferSize = 32 * 1024;
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(filename),
                bufferSize)
        );
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dos.writeShort(data[i]);
    }
} finally {
    dos.close();
}
```

Comment: Using your and @dst's answers it seems to work, at least for output, but it takes about 13 seconds? Is there any reason it's so long?

Comment: Try putting a `BufferedOutputStream` between file and data stream. You might be writing single elements which is painfully slow.

Comment: I was using your first code, it still takes 13 secs with the buffer. I'll try the second one with the buffer and see if that fixes it.

Comment: If I give up on flexibility by using the DataOutputStream, it takes 11 seconds, so I guess I'll stick with the original OOS. But is it normal for ~5 million shorts to take that time to write on a phone?

Comment: @NiBr isn't `new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename)))` helping? value conversion is unfortunately pretty slow in Java since it's actually shifting and bitmanipulating each thing. Lower lever languages can simply interpret memory in the desired way and iterate byte-wise over a short array.

Comment: oops, didn't see that it didn't help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35020/discussion-between-nibr-and-zapl)

Answer (score 1):

Use the file streams directly without buffering through an `ByteArrayOutputStream` / `ByteArrayInputStream`. The `byte[]` is held in memory and not suitable for large potions of data.

Writing to an `new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename))`, you can get your objects back using an `new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename))`. If you want, you can also do some buffering as mentioned in [Christopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18109709/2636001).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the method here: [byte array to short array and back again in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625573/byte-array-to-short-array-and-back-again-in-java) and just write and read the bytearray. I would also recommend using [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) instead of just a FileOutputStream.