# Byte array greater than 255

Tags: java, android, string, bluetooth, byte

I get to be a tool bluetooth number of 16-bit and I need to convert it to a string. I am able to obtain a number up to 255 in this way:

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
String strIncom = new String(readBuf);                              
char c = strIncom.charAt(0);
```

definitely receive up to 255 because "byte" it is 8-bit. I tried to replace bytes with short but I get this error:

```
byte[] cannot be cast to short[]
```

Comment: Do you need to convert byte[] to short[]?

Comment: I would like to get the numbers greater than 255 but do not know how to do @nogard

Comment: @davix10 : Not an answer to your cast problem (you haven't really shown enough code) but do you know that a `byte` in Java is signed so it can only represent +/-127? Or are you manipulating directly with a bit-mask or bit-wise operators?

Comment: Still unclear of what you want to do, but perhaps your issue is more related to the string encoding than raw byte value?

Comment: @Squonk At this time I can get the numbers up to 255, I know that  byte is 8-bit, but do not know how to solve the problem. You need more details?

Comment: @AndrewT. Now do you understand?

Comment: @davix10 what do you mean by 'get numbers up to 255'? where do you 'get' them from?

Comment: Barely. Do you want to convert it to `short[]` instead? If it is, then maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625573/byte-array-to-short-array-and-back-again-in-java) could help. But take note that `String` doesn't have constructor with `short[]` parameter.

Comment: @AndrewT. but if I convert byte in short do not always get the numbers up to 255?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
  ByteBuffer input=ByteBuffer.wrap((byte[])msg.obj);
  short my16bitValue=input.getShort();
```

read about byte order

I'm not sure, whether that is what you want to do...

(you can get a String from that using Short.toString(my16bitValue) ...)