# Android reverse playing pcm file

Tags: android, audio, arrays, pcm

I have a pcm audio file, or byte array of this file. And i need to reverse it and play it.

If i just reverse byte array like this I'm getting noise, so i should reverse only raws or sample raws of pcm.

```
public void reverse(byte[] array) {
          if (array == null) {
              return;
          }
          int i = 0;
          int j = array.length - 1;
          byte tmp;
          while (j > i) {
              tmp = array[j];
              array[j] = array[i];
              array[i] = tmp;
              j--;
              i++;
          }
      }
```

I read a lot, but I didn't find any info of how i can do this.

Data in byte array stores like this(at oneDrive, cuz not enough reputation) :
http://1drv.ms/1DJ0jDr

I'll apreciate any help. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to first convert the byte array to an array type that is appropriate for you samples and then reverse *that* array. For example if your samples are 16-bit then you'll want to convert to an array of shorts.

Alternatively, in the 16-bit case you could keep the data in bytes and then reverse - but in pairs of bytes.

```
public void reverse(byte[] array) {
      if (array == null) {
          return;
      }
      int i = 0;
      int j = array.length - 1;
      byte tmp;
      for (int k = 0 ; i < array.length/2; ++i) {
          tmp = array[j-1];
          array[j-1] = array[i];
          array[i] = tmp;

          tmp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[i+1];
          array[i+1] = tmp;

          j+=2;
          i+=2;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This post helps in converting http://stackoverflow.com/a/5626003/4166904

Comment: This throws an array index out of bound issue for me on line 9. Do you mean `j-=2` ?